# iFrame Redirect Issue - Not Changing the page

Tags: javascript

```
<iframe src="http://runebet.com/" width="80%" height="65%"     name="runeBetAPI"></iframe>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
function RegisterPage() {
window.frames["runeBetAPI"].location = "http://runebet.com/register/";
}
RegisterPage();
</script>
```

This doesn't seem to work/change the content..

Comment: could you explain what you want to achieve exactly and what have you tried?

Comment: So I want it to change the page of the iframe to the register one on function call.

Comment: Neither does `document.getElementById('runeBetAPI').src="http://runebet.com/register"; ` work

Answer (score 0):

The URL should start with http://www. to avoid a server redirection

Answer (score 0):

you can access `iframe` contents from the same domain only read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header).

You can use the following to change the source of the `iframe`.

```
function changeSource(src, frameID) {
    var frame= $('#' + frameID);
    if ( frame.length ) {
        frame.attr('src',src);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

But apparently what looks like looking into what your code is doing the url that you are redirecting to it actually opens a registration form inside modal window, which for some reason is not opening if you access it via an iframe, because if you put the url `http://runebet.com/register/` directly in the iframe and load the page it will still be showing the landing page so it is redirecting but the modal is not popping up that leaves you with the last thing that you have to trigger the `Register` link `click` and that can only happen if you are in the same domain if not maybe someone else knows, i dont.

```
$(window.frames[0].frameElement.contentDocument).find('a[href="/register"]').trigger('click');
```